# Heat loss by radiation reference

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, thermal-radiation

In our lab practice, we measured the rate of heat loss of a copper plate in atmospheric pressure and the rate of heat loss of the same plate in high vacuum ($\sim 10^5 torr$). So all I could find for heat loss in the internet is Newton's law of cooling, which is pretty much elementary (pressure doesn't appear as a variable). I was wondering if someone could give me a reference of where I can read something more profound about rate of heat loss for a metal plate involving radiation of course.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/cootime.html

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of good books in thermal radiation, read Modest for example 
Author : M  Modest    Release Date: 15 Mar 2013Imprint:Academic PressPrint Book ISBN :9780123869449 eBook ISBN :9780123869906 Pages: 904Dimensions: 276 X 216